# .git file and .git directory in git repos

Tags: git

I have a git repository and within sub-folders of that repo, there is another git file.

One of the .git shows it to be a directory while the one within the sub folder is shown as a file, as follows:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 root  staff     91 Oct  1 00:37 .git.  -> file

drwxr-xr-x  13 root  staff    416 Oct  1 00:47 .git.  -> directory
```

I understand that .git folder has all info related to git commits etc. The inner folder which has .git file is created using command:

git  worktree add

The folder structure is as follows:

`Outer directory: /Users/kl/temp/.git` -> .git is a directory here

`git  worktree add abc`

after which Inner directory created :

`/Users/kl/temp/t1/abc/.git` -> .git is a file here

`cat /Users/kl/temp/t1/abc/.git`

`gitdir: /Users/kl/temp/.git/worktrees/abc`

Can someone please let me know in what case a .git file is created and what is the use of that file ? The problem is that a git commit fails from `/Users/kl/temp/t1/abc/` directory. If I delete /Users/kl/temp/t1/abc/.git file, then the commit works fine

If any links to documents/books can be provided to read more about it, then please share. Thanks

Comment: Maybe the empty .git file is a .gitkeep file (it is in an empty directory)?

Comment: No, directory is not empty.     sh-3.2# ls .git
COMMIT_EDITMSG HEAD  config  description hooks  index  info  logs  objects  refs  worktrees
sh-3.2#

Comment: If you can say `ls .git` it's a directory, not a file.

Comment: Ok so you've answered your own question.

Comment: sorry matt, didn't get you. Are you referring to 'git  worktree add'?

Answer (score 1):

> If any links to documents/books can be provided to read more about it, then please share

Here you go. From https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree:

> These settings are made *in a .git file* located at the top directory of the linked worktree.

(My italics.)

Comment: I have following folder structure. Probably I need to read more about what are worktrees, rev-parse etc. Thanks Matt for the link, the described structure matches with mine. The problem is that a git commit is failing from the inner directory. If I delete. git file, then the commit works fine.





`Outer directory: /Users/kl/temp/.git -> directory


git  worktree add abc


Inner directory created : /Users/kl/temp/t1/abc/.git -> file



cat /Users/kl/temp/t1/abc/.git
gitdir: /Users/kl/temp/.git/worktrees/abc`

Comment: Ok but that is not what you asked. Your actual question was explicit and I've answered it. — Note: You cannot have a git repo inside a git repo.  It's incoherent. (Unless you want to get into submodules, but you clearly don't.)

Comment: Thanks Matt. One last query, if you could refer some good O'reilly books/ Videos etc to understand overall git in simple language, that will really really help. I have been trying to learn git for a very long time but I find it very complicated and difficult to understand.

Comment: My own https://www.biteinteractive.com/picturing-git-conceptions-and-misconceptions/ perhaps?

Comment: Thank you Matt, that looks quite interesting. I will go though it.